# Laravel Elequent relationship method naming convension

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent-relationship, laravel-relations, dynamic-properties

I have a strange behavior in naming model relationship in my laravel application (Laravel 9, PHP 8.1)

I have two models

```php
class User extends Model
{
    public function userSocialProviders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(UserSocialProvider::class);
    }
}
```

```php
class UserSocialProviders extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

When trying to fetch the relation using dynamic property it returns null

```php
dd($user->userSocialProviders);   // null
```

it only works if I renamed the method to `providers`

```php
class User extends Model
{
    public function providers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(UserSocialProvider::class);
    }
}
```

then it returns the desired result

```php
dd($user->providers);   // Collection<UserSocialProvider>
```

I don't know the reason behind that and of course it's a very bad name.
`$user->providers` doesn't mean anything related to `socialAccounts`

any help How to change the method name and still use the dynamic properies ?

Comment: what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Laravel 9, PHP 8.1